# Default DNS nameserver for Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: network-manager, 17.10, dns, dnsmasq

While looking some old `dnsnameserver` posts, just noticed the following points.

Default `nameserver` for

- Ubuntu desktop 12.04 was `127.0.0.1`
- Ubuntu desktop 14.04 was `127.0.1.1`
- Ubuntu desktop 17.10 is `127.0.0.53`

Is there any specific reason to change the default `nameserver` to `127.0.0.53` by default ? Or is it just a random number(`53`) ?

Answer (score 1):

It's just an ordinary loopback IPv4 address... All IPv4 addresses begining with `127` are loopback addresses.

Ubuntu 17.10 uses [systemd-resolved](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html) as the default local caching name resolver; using a rarely used loopback IPv4 address enables it to coexist with other local caching resolvers. As far as I know no other well-known application uses `127.0.0.53` by default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read somewhere that `dnsmasq` server in `12.04` is not cache server due to security issues. So dnsmasq in `17.10` is caching ? I have little knowledge in this area. probably i need to try to understand more to avoid such doubts i think. Anyway thanks again.

Comment: @Rooney: 17.10 uses systemd-resoved. Try `systemd-resolve --status`.